# How can I override css of 3rd party(recaptcha) in scope css?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, grecaptcha

I want to hide badge of google recaptcha. If I inspect element, it looks like this :

[image]

I try like this :

```
<style scoped>
   .grecaptcha-badge {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

But it does not works

If I try like this :

```
<style>
   .grecaptcha-badge {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

It works

But for this case, I have to use `scope` because I only want to hide the badge of recaptcha on certain pages

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like `scoped` is [nonstandard and generally unsupported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement/scoped), that's quite unfortunate. You could use Javascript to dynamically determine whether you're on one of the pages you want to hide it on, or change those pages such that they have a selector that you can use in combination with `.grecaptcha-badge`

Comment: I've had this problem before. The only way I could fix it was to scope it myself by adding a unique `id` or `class` to the components root node and use it in the `<style>` also.

Comment: @twharmon  I try `body >>> .grecaptcha-badge {
    display: none !important;
}`. But it does not works. It usually make unique id

Comment: If like this : `<style>
   .grecaptcha-badge {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>`, it works. But it will hide badge recaptcha on all page